# Reference to this in actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe, jdialog

In the constructor of my main window I create a button with the following simple code:

```
JButton jbOptions = new JButton("Options");
buttonsPanel.add(jbOptions);
jbOptions.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    new OptionsDialog();
  }
});
```

Now, I need to pass to the constructor of the `OptionsDialog` a reference to the JFrame. How to do that? `this` is a reference to `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new OptionsDialog(MyJFrame.this);
```

`MyJFrame` being the name of the enclosing class, obviously.